# Where can I find a JSON weather API for an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, json, weather-api

Most of the ones I've found use XML, and I'd rather just use the JSON Objective-C source code.

Any suggestions?

I have seen this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Comment: http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx

Uses JSON and was mentioned in the related question you have linked to above... So what is the additional criteria for an API that you have not included?

Comment: it's not very good, i live in SF and the weather a mile or two away could be wildly different, and this api only has very minimal data point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Weather APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis)

Comment: @vikingosegundo because JSON is better in many ways, not to mention iOS natively supports JSON now

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito iOS also supports xml natively. For the app it doesn't matter if it is well-formed xml or well-formed JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Weather Underground has an API that returns JSON and XML.  Fair pricing, plus 500 free developer calls a day.  Weather Underground has many local weather stations outside of the NOAA official stations, a good number in the SF area.

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html

Answer (score 4):

**Note: This API is now deprecated by Yahoo and *will not work***!

---

There is an undocumented Yahoo Weather API I discovered after messing around for a while.  Here's a sample link:

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=12844782&u=c

The value after `w` is the WOEID, and `u` is for units.  I'm sure there are more options available for configuring the URL.

Here's what it looks like:

```
{
   "units":{
      "temperature":"C",
      "speed":"km\/h",
      "distance":"km",
      "pressure":"mb"
   },
   "location":{
      "location_id":"ITXX0024",
      "city":"Como",
      "state_abbreviation":"*",
      "country_abbreviation":"IT",
      "elevation":935,
      "latitude":45.81000000000000,
      "longitude":9.08000000000000
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":5.00000000000000,
      "direction":"VAR"
   },
   "atmosphere":{
      "humidity":"40",
      "visibility":9.99000000000000,
      "pressure":982.00000000000000,
      "rising":"steady"
   },
   "url":"http:\/\/weather.yahoo.com\/forecast\/ITXX0024.html",
   "logo":"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/nt\/ma\/ma_nws-we_1.gif",
   "astronomy":{
      "sunrise":"08:01",
      "sunset":"16:42"
   },
   "condition":{
      "text":"Fair",
      "code":"34",
      "image":"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/we\/52\/34.gif",
      "temperature":9.00000000000000
   },
   "forecast":[
      {
         "day":"Today",
         "condition":"Mostly Clear",
         "high_temperature":7.00000000000000,
         "low_temperature":2.00000000000000
      },
      {
         "day":"Tomorrow",
         "condition":"Partly Cloudy",
         "high_temperature":8.00000000000000,
         "low_temperature":2.00000000000000
      },
      {
         "day":"Friday",
         "condition":"Sunny",
         "high_temperature":8.00000000000000,
         "low_temperature":3.00000000000000
      },
      {
         "day":"Saturday",
         "condition":"Mostly Sunny",
         "high_temperature":7.00000000000000,
         "low_temperature":1.00000000000000
      },
      {
         "day":"Sunday",
         "condition":"Sunny",
         "high_temperature":8.00000000000000,
         "low_temperature":1.00000000000000
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Indeed it is, and this has been noted at the top of my answer for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the new Aeris Weather API that we've recently released. Extremely flexible and offers a wide variety of data options with a lot more coming down the road. We also offer a free developer account that allows you for up to 750 hits per day.

http://www.hamweather.com/products/aeris-api/
http://www.hamweather.com/support/documentation/aeris/

Comment: Also, since you are developing an iPhone app, they have an iOS weather framework designed to give you some very easy implementation of weather.